# При переходе на страницу выдает ошибку

Tags: php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /home/bitrix/ext_www/gubkin-crb.bcpi.ru/index.php on line 110

Comment: Выложите строку 110 и соседние.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, было очень интересно. Может, зададите вопрос?

Comment: читаем тут, тут, тут  и тут

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, у вас вместо '**`=`**' в строке 110 использовано '**`=>`**'.

Comment: телепатия! :)

Comment: она самая)) но хоть ошибку назвали - круг сузился

Answer (score 1):

[Посмотрите тут](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=Parse+error%3A+syntax+error%2C+unexpected+T_DOUBLE_ARROW+in+*+on+line+*). Если не покажите нам 110 строку, то кроме как послать Вас в гугл, не чего больше помочь не могу ;-)

Comment: ура, рекурсия!

Comment: 109  <div class="btn1 leftStep" style="background-position: 0% 0px;">    <a href="<?=SITE_DIR?>services/" style="background-position: right -110px;">Все наши услуги</a>   </div>
110</div>
Вот 109 и 110 строка.

Comment: Помогите же!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: <a href="<?=SITE_DIR?>services/"  тут перемудрили, не силён в пхп, но по-моему должно быть $SITE_DIR

Comment: Дело в том что проблема возникла после изменения главной страницу,через редактор.Обнови­ла главную страницу,отобра­зилась за место контента ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /home/bitrix/ext_www/gubkin-crb.bcpi.ru/index.php on line 110.Как исправить ума не приложу...

Comment: Исправил ссылку, насчет Вас то попробуйте полную форму
`<div class="btn1 leftStep" style="background-position: 0% 0px;"> <a href="<?php echo if(isset($SITE_DIR)) echo $SITE_DIR; elseif(defined("SITE_DIR")==true) echo SITE_DIR; ?>services/" style="background-position: right -110px;">Все наши услуги</a> </div> 110</div>`

Answer (score 0):

> Дело в том что проблема возникла после
> изменения главной страницу,через
> редактор.

Видать вы изменили константу. На главной, я думаю, что у вас была строка аля

```
define('SITE_DIR','какое-то_значение');
```

И эту строку вы изменили или удалили вовсе. Попробуйте вернуть на главной

```
define('SITE_DIR','/путь_до/корня_сайта/');
```

Comment: Там вообще нет такого оператора...

Comment: Вот что там 
<div class="recomend clearfix">  
    <h4 class="title med">Рекомендации врачей</h4>

    <div class="wheader-underline"></div>
Я меняла название инфоблока "Рекомендации врачей" на что-то другое,но потом исправила назад, а ошибка переместилась на другую строчцу, т.е. была 111 стала 110